# How to align code in lstlisting?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings

I'm trying to learn the TeX file given by my teacher. I managed to link the C++ file to the listing using:

```
\lstset{language=C++,
    % numbers=left,
    %   stepnumber=1,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily,
    morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}
}
\lstinputlisting[label={code},caption={\textit{Source code} program}, language={C}]{main.cpp}
```

and i got:

[image: this]

I try to use `lstlisting` to explain the code separately. I use:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[label={code},caption={isiArray Function}, language={C}]
        
        void isiArray(int arr[],int *arrLength){
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<*arrLength;i++){
                cin>>arr[i];
            }
        }
    
    \end{lstlisting}
```

But i got:

[image: this]

The code is not aligned on the left as in the previous code. Why is this happening? How to set the alignment to left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `listings` are virtually set verbatim, it considers spaces as well, so your indentation of the entire code block within the `lstlisting` environment is reflected as part of the output. Remove the indentation or use the `gobble` argument to remove an initial set of spaces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={isiArray Function 1}, language={C}, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
        void isiArray(int arr[],int *arrLength){
          int i;
          for(i=0;i<*arrLength;i++){
            cin>>arr[i];
          }
        }
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[gobble=8, caption={isiArray Function 2}, language={C}, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
        void isiArray(int arr[],int *arrLength){
          int i;
          for(i=0;i<*arrLength;i++){
            cin>>arr[i];
          }
        }
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={isiArray Function 3}, language={C}, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
void isiArray(int arr[],int *arrLength){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<*arrLength;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```